# Synchronous 2-legged OAuth

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Using DotNetOpenAuth, we've succesfully implemented asynchronous 2- and 3-legged authentication.

However, we are now facing a situation where we need to perform synchronous 2-legged authentication. At the moment the user presses a button to retrieve data, we need to sequentially 1) obtain a token and 2) perform the data request using this token. An asynchronous 2-legged authentication with callback would result in the retrieval failing the first time and -after the authentication is complete- succeeding when the user presses the button a second time.

In DotNetOpenAuth there is a WebServerClient, a consumer that seems to be able to retrieve an OAuth token based on a consumer Key and Secret, using a 2-legged OAuth step.

The question: Is it possible to `await` the result of this token retrieval?

We're looking for some code samples that explain this concept, because we cannot seem to find sample usages of the `WebServerClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found the solution in the WebConsumer class after all. The way to obtain a token using a synchronous 2-legged OAuth step

```
OAuthGlobals.TokenManager = new InMemoryTokenManager(consumerKey, consumerSecret); 
WebConsumer consumer = new WebConsumer(OAuthGlobals.ServiceProviderDescription, OAuthGlobals.TokenManager); 
OAuthGlobals.AccessToken = consumer.RequestNewClientAccount();
```

The `RequestNewClientAccount()` performs the synchronous step.

Of course, the handler that processes this request needs to be able to process it, so we needed to adapt it for this case.